# C++ dynamic_cast returning NULL although object is of a derived type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic-cast

I have a strange problem, where a dynamic_cast is returning a NULL pointer although the object given in the expression is of a derived type with an inheritance path to the type of the cast.

Unfortunately, i cannot post original code, so here is the situation roughly reconstructed:

I have a clas hierarchy of the following type:

```
class A
class B
class C : public A, B
class D : public C
```

All classes have virtual members.

Now assume I have an object of concrete type D.

In a function where this object is passed in as a B*, i have a cast of this type:

```
C* func(B* pObject)
{
  return dynamic_cast<C*>(pObject);
}
```

The cast returns NULL although the object seems well defined.
VC++ reports it as being a D when looking at the object in debugger when hovering over pObject. (might this be misleading?)

Is this cast supposed to work?
Imo this cast should be allowed. Am i missing something?
What can i do to analyse this issue?
Could there be an issue with the multiple inheritance?

This is on Visual C++ 2013 Pro if it makes any difference.

Comment: Please show how you call `func`.  ([mcve])

Comment: Do `B` have any virtual functions? I.e. is `B` *polymorphic*?

Comment: We're gonna need an example right back from `int main()`. Not enough here.

Comment: Please [create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post actual code. We can *assume* you have accurately presented your bug in *hypothetical pseudocode*.

Comment: NB it doesn't need to be your *oiginal* code, just *real* code that exhibits the bug.

Comment: [Not reproducible](http://ideone.com/gKgTRh) on your example. This can happen if D inherits from C [more than once](http://ideone.com/7P0THQ) or if C is an [inaccessible base for D](http://ideone.com/32PtFS), but not with your type of hierarchy.

Comment: AFAIK there must be a virtual function in your class for this to work.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Indeed, `B` needs to be a polymorphic type. See my answer which took some tweaking to get right ;-).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is elsewhere.

Consider

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {};
struct B {virtual ~B() = default;};
struct C : A, B {};
struct D : C {};
int main()
{
    D d;
    D* pd = &d;
    B* pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pd);
    C* pc = dynamic_cast<C*>(pb);
    std::cout << pc; // this is not nullptr
}
```

This proves that `C*` is reachable from `B*` for an pointer to an object of type `D`, when only `B` (the *source type* in the second cast) is explicitly polymorphic.

See https://ideone.com/ifxYgV

Comment: You are casting in the opposite direction.

Comment: @n.m. Oops. All fixed. Indeed the "source" type - `B` in this instance needs to be polymorphic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time. It confirms that i don't do something fundamentally wrong with the cast. I have myself written a test with the real classes and it shows it works well within that test environment too. I still have the problem in the real app though and i dont know how to track it down. It might be VC++ playing tricks on me and the object isn't really what VC++ wants to make me belief.

Comment: @Scrontch: I really doubt its MSVC2013. Microsoft's compiler has improved a lot since the bad days of version 5.

Comment: I didn't want to say MSVC is bugged. But rather that i may not read its output correctly. in Debug mode, how do i find out what is the concrete type of an object pointed to via a base pointer?

Comment: I've used many versions of Visual Studio on many huge games and never had a problem with dynamic cast. There's a much greater chance something is wrong in your project than for dynamic cast to be broken in Visual Studio.  Since you have not shared a real example with us I'm afraid you're on your own.